# htaccess redirect to new url - QueryString not appended

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am have a problem with redirect

I have a rule like

```
RewriteRule top-offers.html /?index.php&categoryid=50[QSA,L,R]
```

But the QueryString will not be appended in URL.

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess in question

Comment: `RewriteRule top-offers.html /index.php?categoryid=50[QSA,L,R]` Did you miss place the ? in the URL

Comment: Give a space `RewriteRule top-offers.html /?index.php&categoryid=50 [QSA,L,R]`